# Does Tensorflow Provide Pre-Trained Image Segmentation Models?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building a custom machine learning model that requires image segmentation at some point in the pipeline. Does Tensorflow provide pre-trained segmentation models or do I have to train my own model?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) out.

Comment: [Deeplab](https://github.com/bonlime/keras-deeplab-v3-plus) is one of the pretrained image segmentation models. you can also refer to this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) where they use the u-net pre-trained model for image segmentation.Thank You.